# YouTube's playback speed – changing time-stretch algorithm to "variable speed tape recorder" – Does anyone remember how?

Tags: javascript, youtube, html5-video, html5-audio, playback

First of all, I don't know javascript or any other scripting or programming language. Sorry about that.

However, a few weeks ago I discovered somewhere a line that would let you change the way YouTube handles different playback speeds when you typed it on the console. By default YouTube uses some kind of time-stretch algorithm that keeps the pitch same but you obviously get lots of artifacts especially when slowing down the audio.

The command changed it to function like variable speed tape machine – you slow down the audio, the pitch goes down but there are no nasty artifacts. Speed up and the pitch goes higher. That is more musical way to slow or speed up audio and it was quite fun to listen songs at slower or faster speed and hear what they sound like without the need to record them with Audacity and then doing it there or in a DAW.

The problem is that I have forgotten what the line was.

document.getElementsBy????? something something

I thought I wrote it down somewhere but apparently not. Can't even remember where I discovered it. I have tried to Google it but so far I have had no luck.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _"By default YouTube uses some kind of time-stretch algorithm"_ I don't think so. I'm pretty sure YouTube just uses the HTML video `.playbackRate` property to speed up/slow down videos.

Comment: I think your maybe looking for -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/preservesPitch   The default should be true, so YouTube is unlikely doing anything special here.

Comment: Hmm... there seems to be HTMLMediaElement.preservesPitch
property. Maybe the line simply disabled that, leading the audio playback function as I described above?

Comment: On YouTube you could try -> `document.querySelector('.video-stream').preservesPitch = false`

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith! That seems to do the trick.